# When i input two or more strings in codeblocks how can i concatenate them?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm a programming beginner. Please tell me that how can I concatenate two strings or more strings in [codeblocks][1]. Those strings are inputs which can be given by user.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{ 
    char a,b; 
    printf("Enter your first name:-"); 
    scanf("%s",&a); 
    printf("Enter your middle name:-"); 
    scanf("%s",&b); 
    printf("%s",a+b); 
}
```

Comment: Codeblocks IDE uses C, C++ and Fortran programming languages. Learn how to concatenate strings in any one of those languages. If you have problems getting your code to work, share it here.

Comment: I'm sorry..I'm using "C".Here is my question.     #include<stdio.h>
main(){
char  a,b;
printf("Enter your first name:-");
scanf("%s",&a);
printf("Enter your middle name:-");
scanf("%s",&b);
printf("%s",a+b);
}
   Could you please tell me that what is the error of this code?

Comment: try `scanf(" %[^\n]s",name);`

Comment: Nope..Not worked dude...

Comment: You should learn the basics of C first. I will not believe that a book or a good tutorial ressource (or a professor) does not tell the difference between a char and a char array (or a CString). So you must have overread or skipped that chapter...

Comment: @Nidhoegger Yeah..So i should use selflearning..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using char(i.e. char a,b;) which can hold on only one single character(e.g. 'a' or 'x' or 'm') but you want to store a name which is usually a collection of few characters. In C and other programming languages we use **string** to do that. Specifically in C we have to use **char array**.

If you do not know about arrays yet, learn that first.

Comment: ooh..Aren't there other ways to do this without char arrays?

Comment: May be there is but at this moment I cannot think of any.

Comment: You can start with this first http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm and then you will have to look into how to input it.

Comment: Anytime! Keep the questions coming! And if this answer helped you then don't forget to mark this answer as "Accepted"

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the language you are coding in like java, c, etc.
Usually strings are concatenated by a '+' sign .

```
#b,c being String objects assuming you are not coding in c or something
#a is an empty String variable
a=b+c;
```

Comment: I'm sorry..I'm using "C".Here is my question. #include<stdio.h> main(){ char a,b; printf("Enter your first name:-"); scanf("%s",&a); printf("Enter your middle name:-"); scanf("%s",&b); printf("%s",a+b); } Could you please tell me that what is the error of this code?

Comment: @GayanthaAkalanka you should have added this code to your initial question. I have done it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much...I'm a newbie..:D

Comment: No problem! But as for your query in the next answer, c does not have a string type data; so you have to use a char array.

Comment: Aren't there other ways to do this without using char arrays?

Comment: for c there isn't;

Comment: Ah..really? ok then.Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here. The first one has been discussed by sami1592. The second one is concatenating two strings, this usually done by invoking [strcat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/).

Comment: So can't i concatenate them using char arrays?

Comment: Sure you can, but it's not as simple as using a `+` operator and the code you would write would basically do what `strcat` does for you.